# Launch a browser with no title bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a html page which is used and saved as a shortcut to launch a menu. and I want to display something like this.

[Very big image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmLcN.jpg)

The ones highlighted in red are the ones i want to disable.

I searched online for answer but found windows.open is one option but i don't think that will apply here because that will open a new browser window with the given conditions. Is there a way to open my html page with a fixed width and height, With no address bar, no option to minimize and maximize, and no option to open a new tab?

Comment: So you want to block the client browser ?

Comment: Just say for a minute this was possible - how do you think your users would like that you think you know better than them how they like to use their browsers?

Comment: Google "webapp". Thats all you can do

Answer (score 6):

You can only open popups with the settings you are asking for.

You have no control over the browser settings when a user navigates to your page.